# data type not understood during attaching some matrix blocks to each other

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my attempt to build a big matrix out of some smaller ones:

```
import numpy as np

lambda1 = 1
lambda3 = 0.03

def create_Lambda_matrix(lambda1, lambda3):
    Lambda = np.zeros((6,7))
    temp3by3 = 2*np.matrix([[lambda1, lambda3, lambda3],[lambda3, lambda1, lambda3],[lambda3, lambda3, lambda1]])
    temp2by2 = 2*np.matrix([[lambda1, lambda3],[lambda3, lambda1]])
    Lambda = np.bmat([[temp3by3, np.zeros(3,4)]],
                       [np.zeros(2,3), temp2by2, np.zeros(2,2)],
                       [np.zeros(2,5), temp2by2]])
    return Lambda

Lambda = create_Lambda_matrix(lambda1, lambda3)
print(Lambda)
```

But a `data type not understood` error is returned at the line in which `Lambda` is about to be generated.

```
Message=data type not understood
  Source=C:\Users\Matinking\source\repos\PyMy\PyMy\PyMy.py
  StackTrace:
  File "C:\Users\Matinking\source\repos\PyMy\PyMy\PyMy.py", line 41, in create_Lambda_matrix
    Lambda = np.bmat([[temp3by3, np.zeros(3,4)],
  File "C:\Users\Matinking\source\repos\PyMy\PyMy\PyMy.py", line 46, in <module>
    Lambda = create_Lambda_matrix(lambda1, lambda3)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Provide complete error message.

Comment: @Sociopath: Please check the added `StackTrace`.

Comment: the argument of bmat doesn't make sense. It has too many braces, and the lists included have len 2,3,2. I think this is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error when you define `temp2by2`. Use instead:

```
temp2by2 = 2*np.matrix([[lambda1, lambda3],[lambda3, lambda1]])
```

However you are likely getting the error when you generate you `np.zeros` matrices. You have to provide the size of the matrix using an array-like type, as you do in `Lambda = np.zeros((6,7))`